# Which database does docker use?

Tags: database, docker

Is there anyone who knows which type of database does docker use?

I opened a file /var/lib/docker/swarm/worker/task.db and don't know what its contents mean but I can't get it.

I can't turn on the computer again because it is related to an legal case.

Is there anyone who knows this?

Comment: a `file /var/lib/docker/swarm/worker/task.db` would have helped you

Answer (score 4):

Its `sqlite3`.

But I am curious what you gonna do with this information!!!

Comment: .. or with the contents of just this file. Mysterious question indeed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can't open it with sqlite Viewer ㅜㅜ

Comment: What are you going to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

It's called as boltdb, https://github.com/boltdb/bolt. If you install and build from the project's page, it comes with a cli client or you can use a TUI client built for it, https://github.com/br0xen/boltbrowser